Get more info from Message: "Error in R_nc4_def_var_float: NetCDF: NC_UNLIMITED in the wrong index"
When trying to add a new variable into an existing netcdf by using ncvar_add, I get the error message above. I have checked with all verbose output from the opened file nc_open and the variable defining ncvar_def, that the only unlimited attribute is set for dimension time. I use spatial and time coordinates from the old file to attach it to the new variable. This is what the debug output revealed:
"ncvar_add: varname to add= bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: about to redef ncid= 65536"
[1] "ncvar_add: creating 4 dims for var bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: working on dim > time < (number 1 ) for var bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: dim time has been seen before"
[1] "ncvar_add: working on dim > lon < (number 2 ) for var bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: dim lon has been seen before"
[1] "ncvar_add: working on dim > lat < (number 3 ) for var bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: dim lat has been seen before"
[1] "ncvar_add: working on dim > plev < (number 4 ) for var bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: dim plev has been seen before"
[1] "ncvar_add: figuring out ncid to use"
[1] "ncvar_add: ncid2use= 65536 name2use= bbi"
[1] "ncvar_add: creating float precision var bbi"
Error in R_nc4_def_var_float: NetCDF: NC_UNLIMITED in the wrong index
Name of variable that the error occurred on: "bbi"
[1] "nc_create: C call returned value -47"
[1] "----------------------"`


How can I find out, where my variable or my file is wrong? I have no idea anymore what I did wrong.
I use  ncdf4 package version ncdf4_1.22_20231127 | underlying netcdf library version 4.9.2 of Aug  3 2023 11:32:20 $"
I am searching for more concise debug output, which one is the wrong index or where it does appear. Or if this error message is a sign for incompatible ncdf libs?
